# Converting raw to HDF5

Tags: hdf5

I am new on HDF5. I am trying to convert a hyperspectral image raw file to a HDF5 file, but I do not find the proper way. Does anyone know how to convert a raw file in a HDF5 file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "*hyperspectral image raw file*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to learn HDF5 APIs. If you use C++, you can this detailed document http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.intro.html should be very useful.
Moreover, you can use the high-level APIs (http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/HL/). It should be more convenient since all you need is to create a new HDF5 dataset.

Youn can also consult the HDF help desk help@hdfgroup.org. They are always willing to help every user very patiently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a binary file to a HDF5 file, you need:

- to know the specification of your raw binary file (how data are stored)
- to know how to store data in your HDF5 file

If I had to do such a conversion, I would use a high level language to do the reading and writing. I would use Python (2 or 3), `struct` to do the reading, and the library [h5py](http://www.h5py.org) for exporting hdf5 file. It would cause much less trouble than using compiled language like C, C++ and Fortran.